# Get tweets from TWTRUserTimelineDataSource (TwitterApi)

Tags: ios, swift3, twitter-fabric

i'm using **Fabric** and **TwitterAPI** for fetching tweets of a specific user
my code:

```
class FetchTwitterTableViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("FETCHING....")

    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "MyTwitterUsername", apiClient: client)

}}
```

the above is showing tweets of desired user in a custom ViewController,

here i wanna access these tweets individually by their ids, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `withJSONArray` method

```
class FetchTwitterTableViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("FETCHING....")

    self.dataSource =  TWTRTweet.tweets(withJSONArray: yourIdArr as [AnyObject]) as [AnyObject])

  }
}}
```

Comment: hey man! thanks for responding, i saw your answer and quiet  get the idea on how to fetch Tweets by id still i dont know how to get ids from my Datasource   cause here i'm not getting any access on this fetched data `self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "MyTwitterUsername", apiClient: client)
`

Comment: Twitter has a method `client.sendTwitterRequest`, check it and create `yourIdArr` with the desired values.